# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, text, html-table

I am trying to get values from a table and i got this error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')** can someone please help to resolve it?

js

```
 const cards = document.getElementById('cards')
 const templateCarrito = document.getElementById('template-carrito').content

 const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
 let carrito = {}

 cards.addEventListener('click', e => {
     addCarrito(e)
 })

const pintarCards = toolList => {
                toolList.forEach(producto => {
                   
                    templateCard.querySelectorAll('td')[0].textContent = producto.tbl_herramienta_ID
                    templateCard.querySelectorAll('td')[1].textContent = producto.tbl_herramienta_NOMBRE
                    templateCard.querySelectorAll('td')[2].textContent = producto.tbl_herramienta_DESCRIPCION
                    templateCard.querySelector('.btn-success').dataset.id = producto.tbl_herramienta_ID
                    const clone = templateCard.cloneNode(true)
                    fragment.appendChild(clone)
                })
                cards.appendChild(fragment)
            }

            // agregar al arrito
            const addCarrito = e => {
                if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-success')) {
                    console.log(e.target.dataset.id)
                    setCarrito(e.target.parentElement)
                }
                e.stopPropagation()
            }

 const setCarrito = objeto => {
                
                const producto = {
                    id: objeto.querySelector('.btn-success').dataset.id,
                    nombre: objeto.querySelectorAll('td')[1].textContent,
                    descripcion: objeto.querySelectorAll('td')[2].textContent,
                    cantidad: 1
                }
                console.log(producto)
   
            }
```

i got an error in `nombre: objeto.querySelectorAll('td')[1].textContent, descripcion: objeto.querySelectorAll('td')[2].textContent,`

Answer (score 1):

`templateCard.querySelectorAll('td')` does not seem to give you as many results as you expect, hence the call to `.textContent` fails (one of three elements seem to be `null`). You can try to log the results of that selector to see what the resulting elements are.

Comment: `templateCard.querySelectorAll('td')` shows results but in trying to get those data i get the error. I using vanilla javascript. what another method can i use?

Comment: Does it show three results? Also: beware, the browsers will evaluate your console.log() asynchronously. This leads to confusion. I.e. make sure that those three `<td/>` nodes are present at the time you run this code. They might get added later, which would break your logic.